# How to put delay inside a arraylist in android

Tags: android, android-studio, arraylist

Hey guys i want to put 2 second delay in each code inside of the arraylist. How can i do this? Sorry newbie in android developing. Thanks for any help.

Here is my code.

```
  private ArrayList<double[]> points = new ArrayList<>();
{
    points.add( new double[] {-2885, 4537} );
    points.add( new double[] {-2903, 3916} );
    points.add( new double[] {-3236, 3883} );
    points.add( new double[] {-3233, 3657} );
    points.add( new double[] {-3552, 3638} );
    points.add( new double[] {-3570, 2661} );
    points.add( new double[] {-2735, 2651} );
    points.add( new double[] {-2720, 2613} );
    points.add( new double[] {-2634, 2613} );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Thread class to make delay during the execution.

```
try{
Thread.sleep(seconds to delay*1000)
}
catch(Exception e)
{
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

or you can use the Asynchronous Task to delay

```
public void callAsynchronousTask() {
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        TimerTask doAsynchronousTask = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                          Log.e("data","5 sconds");
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        };
        timer.schedule(doAsynchronousTask, 0, 5000); //execute in every 5 s
    }
```

Comment: Sorry. Can you show me how to apply my code in callAsynchronous task. Sorry sir. I dont know how to apply my code, cause im newbie in android.